# Iterating though object in array in React (ES6)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an object in array like the following:

```
bears: [
{
 Yogi: "123kg",
 Pooh: "110kg",
 Grizly: "112kg",
 BooBoo: "200kg",
 Polar: "100kg",
}
]
```

`

What is the best way to iterate through such object in order to display both names and values in the row, like returning something in the type of: `<p>${name} ${value}</p>`

So I would display:

Yogi 123kg

Pooh 110kg

Grizly 112kg

BooBoo 200kg

Polar 100kh

Comment: It's not really an object. It's an array of 1 object. (And it's definitely not JSON. The keys would need to be in double quotes like "Yogi")

Comment: Adult polar bears are much heavier than that, but I won't downvote for a data error:)

Answer (score 4):

It's an array containing an object, not an object. Anyway just get the first item of the array.

This should work:

```
Object.keys(bears[0]).map(key => <p>{`${key} ${bears[0][key]}`}</p>);
```

Comment: yes, it's an array containing object, just like in the description.

Comment: and nope, this doesn't work, I don't get strings, I got all objects with this solution.

Comment: @EdwardKluczkowski you know you just edited the description and then complained about the description being accurate and we can see your edits, right? It should work now, I copied your OP and you were missing the " ` ". You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the JSON object's structure itself is wrong.
It should be structured like this:

```
var bears = [{
  name: "Yogi",
  weight: "123kg"
}, {
  name: "Pooh",
  weight: "110kg"
}, {
  name: "Grizly",
  weight: "112kg"
}, {
  name: "BooBoo",
  weight: "200kg"
}]
```

Then you can go ahead and iterate through it using a for loop inside of the `render()` method like this.

```
render() {
    var bearElements = [];
    for (var bearIndex = 0; bearIndex < bears.length; bearIndex++) {
      bearElements.push(
        <p>{`${bears[bearElements].name}` `${bears[bearElements].weight}`}</p>
      )
    }

    return (
      <div>{bears}</div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: make sure to try my code I haven't compiled it.

Comment: cannot change JSON structure. Thats the whole point my friend...